# How can we use like in yii Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Could any one please tell me the syntax for like in yii mongodb .I would like to search for a particular name using like as in sql from mongo db collection.How can we write the query for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MongoRegex object: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php which is compatible with components like YiiMongoDBSuite.

It uses a regular expression to match so `%sammaye%` in SQL = `new MongoRegex('/sammaye/')` in MongoDB.

#### Edit

To search by `sammaye%` you can do `new MongoRegex('/^sammaye/')` as asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194639/like-function-with-yii-mongo-db

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ActiveRecord in Yii2, you should choose simple *like* part in the where condition:

```
ActiveRecord::findOne(['like', 'field', 'query'])
```

For more information see related docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

or of course there are also available the [PHP's MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) commands:

```
$mongo = \Yii::$app->mongodb;
$collection = $mongo->getCollection('your collection name');
$result = $collection->find(['field' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^stratswith')]);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no **like** support. But based on your requirement, you can use the [regex support](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).

Below are the examples from their [SQL to MongoDB query mapping chart.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "%Joe%" = db.users.find({name:/Joe/})
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "Joe%" = db.users.find({name:/^Joe/})
```